# Bundling Style Sheets and Scripts from Different Folders

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bundle, bundling-and-minification

In ASP.NET MVC5 application, I have multiple CSS and JS files that I'm trying to bundle them using below code

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/myBundles/css").Include(
          "~/lib/css/nivo-slider.css",
          "~/css/core.css",
          "~/css/shortcode/shortcodes.css",
          "~/style.css",
          "~/css/responsive.css",
          "~/css/color/color-core.css",
          "~/css/custom.css",
          "~/myDefaultSS.css"
          ));
```

I use it in _Layout page like this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/myBundles/css")
```

When using it, I see below in the hmlt source of my page

```
<link href="/myBundles/css?v=xt5fim6H60Umm4DuM_5iVudeIEOkrcbgXzG0o3CHtlU1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

After using this, my web pages are not showing properly. I think it's because I am bundling files from different directories. Is that right? How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: no, the folders could be different locations. How do you add this to your layout page? please provide its code

Comment: could you check the page source of your site when loaded in browser? does it include proper css files as you referenced in your bundle? e.g: `<link href="/lib/css/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/> ...`

Comment: added page source

Comment: what happen if you open that link in your browser? `/myBundles/css?v=xt5fim6H60Umm4DuM_5iVudeIEOkrcbgXzG0o3CHtlU1`. it seem its optimized to have one css link. Please test if you set debug=true as: `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework=.../>` in `web.config:<configuration><system.web>`

Comment: It opens a css.txt file in notepad. it contains all those css files in one place.

Comment: I access the file through this link: http://localhost:55207/myBundles/css?v=xt5fim6H60Umm4DuM_5iVudeIEOkrcbgXzG0o3CHtlU1

Comment: I see some errors on the top of that file: (225,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@import', many lines like that.

Comment: Please test if you set debug=true in web.config as: <compilation debug="true" targetFramework=.../> under node:<configuration><system.web>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use `@import` css directives when bundling styles. If you publish a release build of your site it didn't work. If you inspect the network traffic [F12], you see the imported css file is not found on the network, because optimization don't replace `@import` url with the correct path.

So, Don’t use bundling with imported css-files OR turn off bundling optimization and optimize them by another way.

Optimization can be turned off by the following line in Web.Config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

Also, you can use this code in C#:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

[[Reference]](http://sde03.azurewebsites.net/?p=5191)

Comment: I did this, but in HTML it generates multiple reference not only one. in this case what's the point of having bundle?

Comment: actually the rendered html is not so important for coder, but the bundles keep your code cleaner and add ability to add selective content in different conditions..